# Why is $Tor_0(A,B) = A\otimes B$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

We define a free resolution of an abelian group $A$ to be a level-wise free chain complex $\tilde A$ such that $H_0 (\tilde A) = A$.

Also, we define $Tor_k (A,B)$ to be $H_k(...\rightarrow \tilde{A_2}\otimes B \rightarrow \tilde{A_1}\otimes B \rightarrow \tilde{A_0}\otimes B \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow ...)$ for some free resolution $\tilde{A}$ of $A$.

I saw in multiple places that $Tor_0(A,B) = A\otimes B$, but I couldn't quite formalize why, and all proofs I found used abstractions I don't quite grasp.

Can anyone please give a proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\operatorname{Tor}_0(A,B)$ is the cokernel of the map $\tilde A_1\otimes B\to \tilde A_0\otimes B$. Since tensoring with $B$ commutes with cokernels, this is precisely $\operatorname{coker}(\tilde A_1\to\tilde A_0)\otimes B$. Now observe that $A=H^0(\tilde A)=\operatorname{coker}(\tilde A_1\to\tilde A_0)$ holds and you are done.

Comment: Why does tensoring commute with cokernel though? I think this might be the specific point I don't understand

Comment: The abstract answer is that $-\otimes B$ has a right adjoint, namely the functor $\hom(B,-)$. You can also combine the universal properties of tensoring and of the cokernel to show that both commute (by proving that you get the same universal property no matter whether you take the cokernel of the tensor product or you take the tensor product of the cokernel).

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it's not that hard of an ordeal to show the isomorphism by hand, and then everything falls into place.